# Attaching event emitter to socket.connected

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, electron, polling

I am currently writing an Electron app, for which in the main process I want to talk to a server over websockets.

Part of my main process' code base depends on the user's socket connection status. I require the `socket.io-client` library

```
const socket = require('socket.io-client')(host);
```

which gives me access to the variable `socket.connected`, which is `true` or `false` according to whether a connection is established to the server.

Thus, what I would like is to attach an event emitter to this variable. I have made it to work with polling

```
var events = require('events').EventEmitter;
var event = new events();

// Emits successfully every 200ms 'Connection: true|false'
event.on('status', function(status){
  console.log('Connection: ', status);
});

setInterval(function() {
  let status = socket.connected;
  event.emit('status', status);
}, 200);
```

but was wondering whether this truly is the way to implement it. To me it seems strange to have to resort to polling in an async framework like nodejs. On the other, I could not find other ways to implement. Best-case scenario would be to attach somehow an event emitter directly to `socket.connected`, but was unable to find how to do that. Could anybody advise me on a better way to implement?

Thanks

Comment: What event do you actually want to be notified of?  `socket.io-client` is for connecting to other socket.io servers as a client.

Comment: Well, afaik that's exactly my use case: My electron app is connecting as a client to a socket.io server...

Comment: And, what event do you want to be notified of?

Comment: Perhaps my post was not clear... socket.io-client keeps track of connection to the socket server on `socket.connected=true|false`. Whenever this variable changes `true->false`/`false->true` I wish to emit that change.

Comment: That's exactly what my answer below shows.  The socket already emits an event when it becomes connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get notified of the completion of a client connection with the `connect` event:

```
socket.on('connect', function() {
    // client socket is now connected to the server
});

socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    // client socket is now disconnected from the server
});
```

Documentation for client events here: http://socket.io/docs/client-api/#manager(url:string,-opts:object).  There are other events in that doc if you also want to see other things like a reconnect.